# Is there a faster way to execute the following SQL request?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the following columns :

```
id, name, domain, added, is_verified
1, "First Google", "google.com", DATE(), 1
2, "Second Google", "google.com", DATE(), 1
3, "Third Google", "google.com", DATE(), 1
4, "First disney", "disney.com", DATE(), 1
5, "Second disney", "disney.com", DATE(), 1
6, "Third disney", "disney.com", DATE(), 0
7, "First example", "example.com", DATE(), 0
8, "Second example", "example.com", DATE(), 0
```

And the following request :

```
SELECT domain FROM mytable WHERE domain NOT IN 
    (SELECT domain FROM mytable WHERE is_verified = 1 GROUP BY domain)
GROUP BY domain ORDER BY added DESC;
```

The main idea behind this request is to get all the `domain` that doesn't have a `is_verified` at true.

In the example above, this would only return "example.com" one time.

The request works well, but takes time to execute (I have thousands of entries). Is there an other way to make this request that would be faster and efficient ?

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In my eyes, your table is not correctly normalized as multiple rows span one single logical entity (depending on the domain). Also, does only the latest `added` entry count or is a domain verified if any rows has `is_verified = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT domain 
FROM mytable 
group by domain 
having max(is_verified) = 0
ORDER BY max(added) DESC
```

I added the `order by` clause. You have to decide which `added` record you want to take for each domain. I chose the max added value of a domain.

Comment: I've run your command, and it took 1 minutes and 6 seconds to execute over more than 800,000 rows. The other response has been executed for more than 10 minutes now and is still running. So I accepted your answer :) Thanks !

Comment: Do you have indexes on `domain` and `added`? This kind of query should return results in a few milliseconds. Look at the output of `explain select ...` It tells you where it does not use indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check:

```
SELECT T1.Domain
FROM mytable T1
LEFT JOIN mytable T2 ON T2.domain = T1.domain AND T2.is_verified = 1
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @TESTDOMAIN TABLE (id int, name varchar(100), domain varchar (100),  added datetime, is_verified bit)

insert into @testdomain (id, name, domain, added, is_verified)
SELECT 1, 'First Google', 'google.com', GETDATE(), 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 'Second Google', 'google.com', GETDATE(), 1 UNION
SELECT 3, 'Third Google', 'google.com', GETDATE(), 1 UNION
SELECT 4, 'First disney', 'disney.com', GETDATE(), 1 UNION
SELECT 5, 'Second disney', 'disney.com', GETDATE(), 1 UNION
SELECT 6, 'Third disney', 'disney.com', GETDATE(), 0 UNION
SELECT 7, 'First example', 'example.com', GETDATE(), 0 UNION
SELECT 8, 'Second example', 'example.com', GETDATE(), 0

SELECT T1.Domain
FROM @TESTDOMAIN T1
LEFT JOIN @TESTDOMAIN T2 ON T2.domain = T1.domain AND T2.is_verified = 1
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Nice way to put it :) I runned both the present answers and the other one took 1 minute and 6 seconds to run, yours is still runnig after 10 minutes, that's why I accepted the other. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CyrilN. does your table have indexes on columns `domain` and `is_verified`? This query should be much faster than any `GROUP BY` query (but only if the table is properly indexed).

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have to use a sub select? Wouldn't that deliver the same result?

```
SELECT domain 
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY domain 
  HAVING sum(is_verified)<1;
```

Comment: This query also returns `disney.com`.

Comment: @axiac Thanks for pointing that out, I indeed understood the question different. Fixed, although I'd be the first to acknoledge that using a `HAVING` clause is everything but efficient...